# Meteor Twitter Help (Meteor NOOB)

Tags: twitter, meteor

I just started learning MeteorJS and after completing the tutorial, I decided to play around with the Twitter API. Initially, I followed this tutorial

http://artsdigital.co/exploring-twitter-api-meteor-js/

Once completing that, what I wanted to do is scrape data from a tweet and display it on the client side.

N/A = proper authentication

Here's the code I've written:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Session.setDefault('screen_name', 'John');
    Template.hello.helpers({
       screen_name: function () {
          return Session.get('screen_name');
       }
    });

    Template.hello.events({
      'click button': function () {

       T.get('search/tweets',
       {
          q: '#UCLA',
          count: 1
       },
       function(err,data,response) {
          var user_name = data.statuses[0].users.screen_name;
          Session.set('screen_name', user_name);
       }
    )
  }
 });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.startup(function () {
// code to run on server at startup

var Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit');

 var T = new Twit({
     consumer_key:         'N/A', // API key
     consumer_secret:      'N/A', // API secret
     access_token:         'N/A', 
     access_token_secret:  'N/A'
   });
 });
}
```

What I believe the problem is that, the 'click button' function, the 'T' is seen to be undefined so the compiler doesn't know what that is or where it came. That thought did spark a thought in my mind to move what I have written inside the

```
if (Meteor.isServer)  to  if (Meteor.isClient)
```

But to no avail. It didn't work. What my reasoning is that once Meteor starts, the server starts, so if the server declares the variable T, shouldn't we be able to access it on the client side too?

I'm not sure if my approach is correct/don't know the conventions of Meteor/Meteor NOOB..so if someone could please help me, that will be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: There's code that runs on your server and code that runs in your browser (client). So if you want to use `T` server-side as well as client-side, you have to define it in a common part (outside of both `isServer` and `isClient`), so that both the client as well as the server run it. Not sure if you're using the API correctly though. Also, have a look at the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Comment: @Oskar I actually thought that way too and attempted that as well, and I received the error Meteor.npmRequire is not a function. And the syntax for the API is being correctly, I can guarantee you that. I followed the tutorial from the link posted in my post and its the way that REST API calls are made. Moreover, putting the API keys outside the isServer will make it open for the public to see and that would not be chill

Comment: it's not defined on the client, you can use meteor methods and meteor calls to call it from the client.

Answer (score 0):

You put a "var" declaration in front of your "T" variable. This binds the scope to the server side context of the app. I bet if you got rid of the var and made "T" global, then you would be able to access it from the client side as well.